# Making pdf files from each array's object

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create pdf file from each object in an array.

```
[
   {
      name: jack,
      age: 20,
   },
   {
      name: daniel,
      age: 22,
   }
];
```

first I try to catch each object.

```
var proceed = 0;
arrayObj.forEach((tasks, index) => {

  if (index === proceed) {
    tasks.forEach(task => {
      $(this).tableRow(task)
    })
    $(this).singlePdf()
  }
  proceed++
})
```

**dynamic table**

```
$.fn.tableRow = function(task){
    var row = "<tr><td"+task.name+"</td><td>"+task.age+"</td></tr>";
    $("tbody").append(row);
};
```

**pdf**

```
$.fn.singlePdf = function(){
    html2canvas(document.getElementById('a4'), {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            var data = canvas.toDataURL();
            var docDefinition = {
                content: [{
                    image: data,
                    width: 500
                }]
            };

            pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download("table.pdf");
        }
    });
}
```

the problem here. when I run it, I am creating multiple pdf file, but it's putting all objects to each pdf...

this part of code not running as I expected.

```
  if (index === proceed) {
    tasks.forEach(task => {
      $(this).tableRow(task)
    })
    $(this).singlePdf()
  }
  proceed++
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: In your code for `singlePdf`, if you getting the same element for every document (`document.getElementById('a4')`).  This code should instead work with only the element you are expecting to output for that document

Comment: I tried to use `$("tbody").remove()` on each cycle. but no luck. any suggestions? @Martin